# Rename currency Format to FR ro SFR format

Tags: 2013

I have looked at different forums and sites to find a solution but did not had much luck.

I need to change currency format from F`R. 123,456.00(Switzerland)` to `SFR. 123,456.00(Switzerland)` in SharePoint 2013 when you create a column in a list.

How can I change the format?

[image: Currency]

I suppose I can do a custom column as per suggestion (http://petersullivan.com.au/2009/04/26/defining-custom-columns-in-sharepoint-%E2%80%93-field-types-and-options/
)

Comment: I found a link to custom development. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcurrency.aspx?tduid=(f7c8a6b4a3a43524c60635d464765af8)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-erdgwB31TUWKH7sWjNurEw)()

Answer (score 0):

You might be happier in the long term if you don't do any back-end development but only change how the value is displayed using Client Side Rendering

More complex CSR examples at
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

your (partial) displayTemplate code could be as simple as:

```
function SFRcurrency(ctx, CurrentFieldSchema, CurrentItem, ListSchema){
    return( String.format("SFR {0}",CurrentItem[CurrentFieldSchema.Name]));
}
```

Or maybe the TEXT function in a Calculated Column could do the job

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US